# how to setup ulimit nofile in devcontainer vscode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have problem running `yum update` in docker (terribly slow). Limiting the number of maximum open files seems to solve the problem.

If I run

```
docker run --ulimit nofile=8192 -it --rm cern/cc7-base:latest /bin/bash
```

it works (`ulimit -n` returns the right number inside the container).

Now I would like to do it inside vscode remote, during the building of the container. I have added this line inside `.devcontainer`, inside the field `runArgs`:

```
"--ulimit nofile=1024:8192"
```

I tried also with

```
"--ulimit", "nofile=1024:8192"
```

but when building inside vscode the container I get a very high value when running `RUN ulimit -n`. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is trying to parse everything left of the "=" sign as the flag's key.

```
unknown flag: --ulimit memlock
```

and failing.

Just use an "=" sign instead of a space to separate actual flag name and value

```
"--ulimit=nofile=1024:8192"
```